# WP custom post type not working with other post types in custom query

Tags: wordpress

I have really wierd problem, namely I have 3 types of posts: one is default post and other two (custom) are products and advice. The problem is the advice post type is not included in search (I have added custom post types top search query with pre_get_posts filter). Even if I use custom query and pass an argument 'post_type' => array('post, advice, products') the advice is exluded. But whent I query 'post_type' => 'advice' it's working then.

Anybody has any idea what can cause this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use this. It will work

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array( 'post', 'advice', 'products'),
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$newsQuery = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $newsQuery->have_posts() ) {
   while ($newsQuery->have_posts()) {
        $newsQuery->the_post(); 
        echo get_the_title();
        echo get_the_excerpt();
   }
}
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: are you sure with your third post type? is it "advice" or something else ?

Comment: I'm sure. The thing is when I query advice only it shows posts, but not working when I try to display posts from multiple post types.

Comment: I have done some updates in the query please try with this "post_per_page".

Comment: It's working. The problem was with the polylang plugin. The advice post type was not included in translations in plugin settings. After I changed it it's now working properly.

Comment: @Dinesh it's `posts_per_page` and your answer is right. Only this is problem :)